# Latest version of Whonix-Gateway stuck on "Loading Network Status 30%"

Tags: whonix, connection

- Whonix v15.0.1.3.9.
- Log says clock is sane and there are no errors about time or date.
- Host Internet connection
  is working with Tor Browser.
- Whonix-Gateway VM clearnet
  connection is tested with sudo -u clearnet command (from Whonix
  troubleshooting page) and is able to connect.
- Log message from journalctl is 'Tor daemon
  connection failed: Cannot read
  /var/lib/tor/cached-microsdesc-consensus  No such file.'

This worked until I started using LAN cable to connect to my router instead of wifi. I haven't changed anything else.  ISP, operating system  --  no change. The wifi on my router is broken so I can't use that now anyway, but I think I prefer LAN cable because it's faster so I'll probably keep that anyway.

I've read other questions and answers and they all say CHECK THE TIME! But my log says the clock is sane?

The log just repeats the same message every second:

```
Vanguards 0.3.1 connected to Tor 0.4.3.5 using stem 1.7.1
Tor needs descriptors: Cannot read /var/lib/tor/cached-microdesc-consensus: [Errno2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/tor/cached-microdesc-consensus'
```

Isn't it weird that Tor Browser connects on Host, clearnet on Whonix Gateway connects but Tor on Whonix Gateway hangs??